# Are there any histories of indigenous Americans who were taken to Europe?

Tags: native-americans, early-modern, age-of-discovery

I have read brief accounts of indigenous Americans who were taken to Europe in the wake of Columbus's arrival, including a family of Inuit who were taken to meet Elizabeth I but died shortly after arrival. Does anyone know of any more detailed studies or comprehensive histories of some of these individuals?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace It's just a hypothesis but the tag "slavery" might be related to the passive nature of "were brought" (repeated 3x).

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Comment: @MCW I edited out the slavery tag, as it is obviously noise, and the OP hasn't justified its use.

Answer (score 9):

A good place to start is the Oxford Bibliographies article [Native Americans in Europe](http://www.oxfordbibliographies.com/view/document/obo-9780199730414/obo-9780199730414-0203.xml). This briefly reviews a number of books which have at least some of what you are looking for, and which will help you pursue your research further. Listed below are a few examples of Native Americans who visited and / or lived in Europe for a time.

---

**Pocahontas**

There are a number of biographies of [Pocahontas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocahontas#Bibliography) (died in England in 1617) listed in the bibliography of the Wikipedia article, including ones by [Grace Steele Woodward](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=IVLPVUnPESIC&source=gbs_similarbooks) and [Charles Dudley Warner](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=FsMtDwAAQBAJ&source=gbs_similarbooks).

---

**Tisquantum**

[Squanto or Tisquantum](https://hsp.org/blogs/hidden-histories/shackshoone-a-mysterious-native-american-in-17th-century-england) (died 1622),

> a Pawtuxet Indian (who had been kidnapped by an English scoundrel and
>   taken along with 23 other Indians to Malaga, Spain to be sold as
>   slaves years before), luckily arrived eventually in England, where he
>   was taught the English language, and after many years absence from
>   America, was, according to Governor William Bradford, 'Providentally'
>   returned to his native Massachusetts only a few weeks prior to the
>   coming of the Mayflower and its colonists.

Again, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squanto) lists several references in its sources, mostly articles or chapters in books.

---

**Attakullakulla**

The Cherokee leader [Attakullakulla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attakullakulla) (c. 1708 - c. 1777) met King [George II in 1730](https://hsp.org/blogs/hidden-histories/shackshoone-a-mysterious-native-american-in-17th-century-england). The [Journal of Cherokee Studies (vol. 3, No. 1)](http://www.cherokeemuseum.org/learn/publications) has an article "Notable Persons in Cherokee History: Attakullakulla." by James C. Kelly.

---

**Donnacona**

[Donnacona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donnacona) (died in France probably in 1539) was a First nations chief who, after [arriving in St. Malo (France) in July 1536](http://www.biographi.ca/en/bio/donnacona_1E.html),

> proceeded to live at the king’s expense. Donnacona accepted
>   questioning, even before a notary, about what he had seen on his
>   voyages; the monk and historian André Thevet, who specialized in
>   interrogating travellers, claimed that he had had a long conversation
>   with Donnacona. The old chief was presented to [François I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_I_of_France): he talked
>   to him about mines which were very rich in gold and silver, of an
>   abundance of cloves, nutmeg, and pepper

There is a short biography of him in the [Dictionary of Canadian Biography](http://www.biographi.ca/en/bio/donnacona_1E.html) and he is mentioned many times in [Richard Hakluyt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Hakluyt#Authored)'s 1600 volume *[The Principal Navigations, Voyages, Traffiques and Discoveries of the English Nation. Vol. XIII. America. Part II.](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/25645/25645-h/25645-h.html)*

---

**Samson Occom**

[Samson Occom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_Occom) (died 1792), a Presbyterian cleric, gave hundreds of sermons in Britain in 1766-67. He is also notable for founding settlements and for being the first Native American to write in English and have it published. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_Occom#works) lists his works, and you may also be interested in William DeLoss Love's *[Samson Occom and the Christian Indians of New England](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=vG7oOpm6TSsC&redir_esc=y).*

Comment: A fine answer. See also Pablo Tac.

Comment: @AaronBrick Good one, maybe worth posting as a separate answer?

Answer (score 2):

One excellent source for such stories is the 1993 article *The First American Discoverers of Europe* by W.C. Sturtevant, in the journal *European review of Native American studies*.